# (node:29504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am currently trying to create a Discord bot using discord.js, I am not that great with Javascript to start with and my syntax probably looks weird and inefficient. What I am trying to do is create a command system where a user on discord enters a command, for example: '!play (youtube link here)' and the bot will play that link in the voice chat. So I checked if the input startsWith !play and then I split the variable up, removed the !play from the array and tried to piece it back together so that the link is the only string remaining, I am probably going about this the wrong was anyway but if someone could help me to either fix this or go a different way about doing it.

Here is my code http://hastebin.com/sutikizora.js

My error:

> (node:29504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Comment: Try to create a mcve: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I hope you realize you have your bot's token in your code. Which means anyone can cause chaos in the servers where your bot is located. Fair warning, friend.